# Compare two lines

Tags: linux, shell, unix

> Compare First column of File B(Name) against first column of File A
>
> - If matched pick second column value (Dawson)
> - If not insert a space
>
> Compare Third column of File B(Age) against second column of file A.
>
> - If matched pick fourth column value (21)
> - If not insert a space
>
> Compare fifth column of File B(Dept) against third column of File A
>
> - If matched pick sixth column value
> - If not insert a space
>
> Compare seventh column of File B(Sex) against fourth column of file A.
>
> - If matched pick fourth column value (Male)
> - If not insert a space

File A Data

```
Name|Age|Department|Sex|
```

File B Data

```
Name|Dawson|Age|21|Sex|Male
Name|Deepak|Age|22|Department|EEE|Sex|Male
```

Expected Output - File C

```
Name|Age|Department|Sex
Dawson|21||Male
Deepak|22|EEE|Male
```

I've tried below but it just take even columns out.

```awk
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2){val=(val?val OFS:"") $i};print val;val=""}' File_B.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the input & output data I see

- file A is a list of keys
- file B has is a list of key + value combinations
- the output should have columns for every key

  - if a row in file B doesn't have a key the column should be empty

This can be easily solved with a hash, map, dict, ... (pick the data structure for your favorite language). Here is a solution using a hash in Perl:

- read each row from file B
- split along `|`: returns an even sized list
- assign list to hash: even entry will be the key, odd entry will be the value
- print out the contents of the hash

  - using the list of keys from file A
  - if a key doesn't exist insert an empty string
  - join the columns with `|` to generate the row string

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use autodie;

die "usage: $0 <headers> <data>\n"
    if @ARGV < 2;

open(my $ifh, '<', $ARGV[0]);
chomp(my $headers = <$ifh>);
close($ifh);

my @headers = split(/\|/, $headers);

open($ifh, '<', $ARGV[1]);
print "$headers\n";
while (<$ifh>) {
    chomp;
    my %row = split(/\|/);
    print join('|',
               map { $row{$_} // '' } @headers
          ), "\n";
}
close($ifh);

exit 0;
```

Test run:

```
$ cat fileA.txt 
Name|Age|Department|Sex|

$ cat fileB.txt 
Name|Dawson|Age|21|Sex|Male
Name|Deepak|Age|22|Department|EEE|Sex|Male

$ perl dummy.pl fileA.txt fileB.txt
Name|Age|Department|Sex|
Dawson|21||Male
Deepak|22|EEE|Male
```

Answer (score 0):

it's possible to do it with small script :

```
#!/bin/bash

cat fileA | sed 's#^|##' | sed 's#|$##' > fileC
for line in $(cat fileB)
do
  unset output
  for col in $(cat fileA | sed "s#|# #g")
  do
    value=$(echo $line | sed "s#.*$col|\([^|]*\)|*.*#\1#")
    [ "$value" != "$line" ] && output=$output"|"$value || output=$output"|"
  done
    echo $output | sed 's#^|##' | sed 's#|$##' >> fileC
done
```